# Resize image from camera in Android

Tags: android, image-resizing, parcelable

I want to resize an image on the sd card and send it to a Web service, the call is asynchronous and `ParcelFileDescriptor` and `CountingInputStreamEntity` use to display progress bar. What should I do to resize and send in the same way ! This is my current code:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
InputStream in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
CountingInputStreamEntity entity = new CountingInputStreamEntity(in, fileDescriptor.getStatSize());
entity.setUploadListener(this);
entity.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
put.setEntity(entity);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image can be re-sized by using [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html)

You need to create a new small width and height of the image like following:

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
        fis.close();

        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resize the camera image you can use the following code in `onActivitResult()`.

```
                 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 options.inSampleSize = 8;

                 Bitmap receipt = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.toString(),options);
```

In which the you can resize the image using `options.inSampleSize` and then pass that image to the web service by your style.

I hope it helps..